# Reading P value from ANOVA table generated by R

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I generated an ANOVA table in R and every boxes are in number except the P value shows "3.387e-05". What does that really mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.387e-05 is computer scientific notation for $3.387 \times 10^{-5}$, or $.00003387$. The "e" in this case means "exponent," and the exponent in this case is -5, while the base is ten.